# How can I use token as global variable between pages?

Tags: flutter, dart, authorization, token, rest

I wanna get users from `rest api`. I have a loginPage, a homePage and getDataPage which is to show the results of http requests. I created 4 buttons on the choicePage which are get, post, edit and delete. I want to show the results of these on the getDataPage but since the auth_token remains on the login page, I don't know how to access it. Also I'm not sure if my code in onPressed is correct.

```
imports

var token;

class ChoicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChoicePageState();
  }
}

class _ChoicePageState extends State<ChoicePage> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController surnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

//-----------------------GET USERS--------------------

  Future<List> get_users(var auth) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('GET', Uri.parse('my-url'));
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }

//-----------------------ADD USERS--------------------

 Future<String> add_users(var auth, user_id) async {
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    var request = http.Request(
        'PUT', Uri.parse('my-url'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "id": user_id,
      "name": nameController.text,
      "surname": surnameController.text,
      "email": emailController.text
    };

    request.body = jsonEncode(map);
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return await response.stream.bytesToString();
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'name'),
                        controller: nameController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'surname'),
                        controller: surnameController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'email'),
                        controller: emailController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('List Users'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        get_users(token);

                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => GetDataPage()),
                        );
                     RaisedButton(
                       color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                       textColor: Colors.white,
                       child: Text('Add User'),
                       onPressed: () {
                          add_users(token);

                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => GetDataPage()),
                      );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I chose as the best to store my jwt token, was using [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). It's a nice package to store data in secure.

Here is an example:

```
final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
// to write on storage
await _storage.write(
      key: 'token',
      value: _tokenValue,
    );

//to read token key in all screens you can do it
token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
```

Comment: Is this method fully compatible with Android & iOS? What I mean to say is, does it require any permissions from the OS that might cause any inconvenience for the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package (it actually uses InheritedWidget and it is just easyer and more convinient) or you can just pass your token to the pages constructors

Answer (score 0):

What you need is state management. Flutter has a great starting point [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)